# Conformal Killing fields satisfy a third order differential equation

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold with smooth metric $g$.

A smooth vector field $X$ is conformal Killing if

$$\nabla_iX_j + \nabla_jX_i - \frac{2}{n} \text{div} X \, \,g_{ij} = 0$$

Proposition 3.2 in the paper "The Boost Problem in General Relativity" by Murchadha and Chistoudoulo claims that any conformal Killing field will satisfy the third order PDE:
$$\nabla^3 X = A\cdot \nabla X + B \cdot X$$
where $A$ and $B$ are linear combination of $Ric$ and $\nabla Ric$ respectively. Does anyone know a proof of this? Any reference is appreciated.